# Php how to make valid url

Tags: php, url

I have file on my server. The name contains 'Ihre Bestellung bei Ticketcorner für Swiss Indoors Basel', but 'ü' is not valid for url.

How can I make it valid or recoded?

I found `mb_convert_encoding` function

I tried it:

```
 $sImageName = mb_convert_encoding($sImageName,"ASCII");
```

But it returns `f?r`  and can't save the file.

Also tried it:

```
$sImageName = rawurldecode($sImageName);
```

But both methods don't work.
Maybe I need another format for it?

How can I fix it and get valid url?

Also try on page use `urlencode()` and i get 'f%C3%BCr'  but when i open link it replace it to 'für' and it doesnt work.

Comment: You mean `$sImageName = mb_convert_encoding($sImageName,"UTF-8");
`  ?  it did not solve problem

Comment: For me doesnt work

Comment: Dont understand your question.. in 'für'

Comment: [**Ths answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/3536236) with be very useful to you

Answer (score 2):

When passing the data in the URL, you have to [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it and then send it in the URL.

```
<?php

echo  urlencode('Ihre Bestellung bei Ticketcorner für Swiss Indoors Basel');
```

While receiving the data, you will have to [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it to get back the original string.

```
<?php

echo  urldecode(urlencode('Ihre Bestellung bei Ticketcorner für Swiss Indoors Basel'));
```